# why does dagger 2 generated components gets deleted on project rebuild?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dagger-2

The problem exists when the code that uses the generated 'Dagger' prefixed on a component is not commented out. If it was commented out, the generated Dagger 2 files are generated.

BookModule

```
@Module
public class BookModule {

    @Provides
    public Book providesBook(){
        return new Book();
    }

}
```

BookComponent

```
@Component(modules = BookModule.class)
public interface BookComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    public Book getBook();

}
```

MainApplication

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    public static BookComponent mBookComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mBookComponent = DaggerBookComponent.builder().bookModule(new BookModule()).build();
    }
}
```

Build.gradle(Application)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle(Project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bryan.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions{
            enabled = true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: '2.10-rc1'
    apt group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: '2.10-rc1'
    compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3'

}
```

Error Stacktrace

```
ERROR: C:\bin\AndroidProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\lloyd\myapplication\MainApplication.java:12.26: DaggerBookComponent cannot be resolved

com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCodeUsingJackApis(AndroidBuilder.java:1931)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.JackTask.doMinification(JackTask.java:148)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.JackTask.access$000(JackTask.java:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.JackTask$1.run(JackTask.java:112)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:223)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.jack.frontend.FrontendCompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.jack.Jack.buildSession(Jack.java:1053)
    at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:540)
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:124)
    ... 8 more
```

---

```
mBookComponent = DaggerBookComponent.builder().bookModule(new BookModule()).build();
```

The code from above is in the MainApplication and it is the problem, if I commented it out, it rebuilds completely fine. But when I left it as it is, it got an error saying the 'DaggerBookComponent' cannot be resolved, by this time the generated DaggerBookComponent is deleted which results in cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2):

When you do a rebuild, the build system looks at the Dagger module and component classes and generates the actual classes that make all of dagger work.  When you do a normal incremental build, it doesn't (it assumes the old versions are still good).  This means when you rebuild if there's some error in your program or in your dagger components/modules it will not be able to rebuild these files.

So basically, you have a bug somewhere, likely (although not necessarily) in your dagger setup.  When you fix it, you'll stop having problems.

Comment: Base on the code above, can you point me out where I might have implemented something differently? I'm new on dagger 2 and I'm trying to implement it the first time on the given code

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong.  I'm curious-  can your app compile without Jack, or are you using Jack only features?  If it can, try removing the JackOptions and see if it builds that way.  My only reason for being curious is that Jack is appearing in the exception being thrown, and I've never tried to use Dagger with Jack.  I don't know that's a problem, its just a possibility.

Comment: I removed the jackOptions and the compileOptions, because jackOptions looks for a java 8 sourceCompatibility. On the rebuild, an error 'Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code. which is because I'm using Java 8. I think the problem mostly lies in my gradle dependencies?

Comment: Ok, so we can't test that.  Gradle dependencies shouldn't cause a problem with Dagger.  You said it compiles if you comment out the DaggerBookComponent, which means there is no real problem, except it seems to be compiling your source code before it generates all the files.  I'm afraid my knowledge of Gradle isn't enough to know why.

Comment: I'll continue on looking for answers. I'd just update this post when I have already have the solution for this. By the way, Thank you Gabe for the help!